# URL Input opentab Issue

Tags: magento2, link, external

[image]

Open in new tab its not working fine in my admin form, its always showing checked if either its value false. In Database value showing correctly but in editpage it is always showing checked.
[link] => Array
(
[setting] => false
[type] => category
[default] =>
[category] => 4
)